# Display Sum of three numbers from input and display the three numbers on the same line

Tags: c#, console, line, addition

```
int sum;
int display;               

Console.Write("Enter three whole numbers:" );

display = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write(display);
Console.ReadKey();
```

How do I Calculate the sum along with displaying the numbers i input on the same line? Eg.input : 123   Solution : 123 = 6

Comment: `123` is a single number not `three whole numbers`

Comment: 1 and 2 and 3 are all whole numbers = 3 whole numbers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
sum = SumOf(str);

public static int SumOf(string s) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (char num in s.ToCharArray())
    {
        sum += (int)char.GetNumericValue(num);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

To use with your code:

```
int display = 0;               

Console.Write("Enter three whole numbers:" );

string s = Console.ReadLine();
foreach (char num in s.ToCharArray())
{
    display += (int)char.GetNumericValue(num);
}
Console.Write("Sum of " + s + " = " + display);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I have no idea how to implement this in my code to try it ,  I am a beginner.

Comment: @TDOTL fixed it for you.

Comment: I tryed and one i ran it it came back with error line 21 unassigned local variable 'display'
)

Comment: Change `int display;` to `int display = 0;`

Comment: Okay it ran the code but now it only shows the sum of the three numbers inputed not the sum along with the three numbers inputed on same line eg i input 123 and get back the sum = 6 and 123

Comment: Change `Console.Write(display);` to
`Console.Write("Sum of " + s + " = " + display);`

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
sum = input.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x)).Sum();
```

You can make it more robust by using `TryParse` and building in a safety net but that is up to you.

Comment: Notice that using `Linq` to this kind of simple stuff makes the code much less readable. Generally you should avoid looking on `string` as `IEnumerable` if you don't have to for the same reason.

Comment: @Some1Pr0 that is why I convert it to a char[] and o not use the raw string. Also, dmitry's answer does not answer the question, does not work with the supplied input and ultimately, over looking these, is the same as mine.

Comment: @Some1Pr0 infact, with his recent edit, he uses the same approach as me, but uses string as an IEnumberable, something you advise against

Comment: Yeah, it's generally the same but his is more readable because of the new lines and indentation. also he converted to int by decreasing chars which is risky and less elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Your Question is confusing, You are prompting the user to enter `Enter three whole numbers:` and in your example you have given `123` as input. whether it is three whole numbers? no. if the question describes your need then you have to code like the following:

```
int a,b,c,sum;          
Console.Write("Enter three whole numbers:" );
a= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
b= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
c= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
sum=a+b+c;
Console.Write("sum={0}",sum);
Console.ReadKey();
```

If the requirement is described in the example then your code should be changed as like the following:

```
 Console.Write("Enter three whole numbers:" );
 int sum= Console.ReadLine().Sum(c => c - '0');
 Console.Write("sum={0}",sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, how do you want user to enter, say, `123`, `45` and `6`?
Since `123456` can be read in *different ways*, e.g. `1` `234` `56`?
I would rather

```
  Console.Write("Enter integer numbers to sum up, separating them by comma"):

  int result = Console
    .ReadLine()
    .Split(',')
    .Select(item => int.Parse(item)) 
    .Sum();

  // test: 123, 45, 67 => 235
  Console.Write(result);
  Console.ReadKey();
```

In case you want to sum up all *the digits* within the given string

```
Console.Write("Enter the numbers which digits you want to sum up"):

String source = Console.ReadLine();

int result = source
  .Select(item => item - '0')
  .Sum();

// test: 12345 => "12345 = 15" since (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15)
Console.Write(String.Format("{0} = {1}", source, result));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Only displays the three numbers inputed on next line does not show sum of three + the three numers inputed together

Comment: The Other Code Only Displays the sum and not along with the three numbers inplemented

Comment: @TDOT L: if you want a *formatted* output, i.e. `"12345 = 15"` then use `String.Format()`: see my edit